# Free video editing software

Tags: video-editor, editing, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a free video editing application that works on windows that must have the following requirements:

- Must be able to take segments (cuts) of videos and add them together.
- Remove audio from the clips and add in a single song for the whole video.
- Add in text that can show/hide at specific points in time.
- Has no horrible watermarks that make the video un-viewable.
- Is free since it is only for fan video use (so not corporate whatsoever).

Cheers.

Similar Questions: [Simple Video Editing Tool?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4233/simple-video-editing-tool) and [What Beginner Video Editing Software Should I Use?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/3018/what-beginner-video-editing-software-should-i-use)

Comment: Welcome Adrian :) I'd recommend you to read this article: http://opensource.com/life/15/1/current-state-linux-video-editing

Comment: [Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/in/products/davinciresolve), [Hitfilm Express](https://hitfilm.com/express) are legally free editors.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look into the new Blackmagic Davinci Resolve, which includes an NLE and color correction tool. it is free and can output a maximum resolution of 3840x2160.

Comment: There is also blackmagic's fusion ***free*** version https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/fusion. not a simple software, but will cover the needs of op. (wow in this world everything is becoming free... good or bad time will tell...)

Answer (score 5):

First off there would be [Lightworks](http://www.lwks.com/), which is free with some limitations. It's a pure abomination and needs a lot of learning an rethinking if you're used to usual NLE software.

Then, what most people don't think of, there would be [Blender](http://www.blender.org/). Actually a 3D rendering software, but also a very good, free/open source video editor. Like all software, it has a learning curve, but there are some really nice tutorials. Just search on YouTube for "blender video editing".

Answer (score 4):

Virtualdub is very good software. Maybe it not cover all the requirements. And it's not exactly "visual" managed as the other, but it'd good and very flexible

Comment: "Not visual managed" - Can you elaborate?

Comment: You do not have so much buttons on the screen, most of the work is done via plugins with very sample interface :)

Answer (score 2):

There is [Microsoft Movie Maker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-live/movie-maker) that comes free with Windows.  It is part of the Windows Essentials package that is available for the recent versions of Windows.  I have found it is quite simple to use and able to perform the simple set of tasks you list.

There are a few online help guides and YouTube videos about using it.  The nice thing is that as it is quite a simple too it is not so complicated to pick up the basics.  I have used it for down car and motorcycle DVR footage.

Comment: This program is no longer available, and the equivalent "Movie Maker: Free Video Editor" does not have a lot of features I need.

Comment: Thank you for the update @GameDeveloper.  It is a shame that such a useful tool has gone.  If you are using YouTube then the video editor they include in creator studio is quite good.  https://www.youtube.com/editor Outside of that the free ones I know of are mostly Linux based.

Comment: Oh cool! Youtube have it :D pretty cool since I wanted to publish on youtube it anyway. Thanks!

Comment: I am pleased my comment provided a helpful answer.  The breadth of tools that YouTube now offers is quite impressive.  I would recommend uploading videos inside the editor unless you want to keep the originals posted too.  Makes splicing things together a bit easier I think.

Comment: If you put that as answer in my question I can accept it and delete my answer :) http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20761/free-tool-to-chain-videos-and-overlap-another-audio-in-a-mixer-like-fashion/20806#20806

Answer (score 2):

You can use VSDC Video editor. It is free. You can add clips, delete a portion of a clip, add text wherever you want, move the text from one place to another, PIP (Picture in picture) is possible.
You can save in many formnats. This SW (VSDC) also works as convertor to convert the videos from one format to another.
This accepts images, videos, audios, etc.
You can also add, delete an audio at any portion of the video

C Nagaraj, Pune, India

Answer (score 1):

Four free & open source video editing software that I would suggest trying out are:

- [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/)
- [OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org/)
- [Shotcut](http://www.shotcut.org/)
- [Olive](https://www.olivevideoeditor.org/)

I have not tested any of them thoroughly, as I generally just use a combination of [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) & [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) for very simple video editing.

Answer (score 0):

power Director is a very good software for Video editing. The current version of the software is not free however occasionally there are offers for free older versions.

I have tried the older version and find that it suffices for most routine editing work and meeting the requirements listed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

[MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) allows to edit videos with Python, which is more flexible in many situations where you don't remember where to find some control at UI.